# Probability of coin toss there are 68% chance that % heads in the range 50% plus or minus SD?

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed $2500$ times. There is about a $68\%$ chance that the percent of heads is in the range $50\%$ plus or minus ($0.5$, or $1$, or $1.5$, or $2$, or $2.5$)?

$\text{P(of coin tossed is 1/2)}=0.50  \pm  \text{SD}$

$n=2500$

$μ=E[X]=x_1∗p_1+x_2∗p_2+x_3∗p_3+...+ x_n∗p_n$
$μ=1*(1/2) + (0*(1/2))=1/2$

The standard error is:

$EX=\sqrt{E[(X−μ)^2]}=P$

$=\sqrt{(x_1−μ)^2∗p_1+(x_2−μ)^2∗p_2+(x_3−μ)^2∗p_3+\cdots+(x_n−μ)^2∗p_n}$
$= \sqrt{(1-1/2)^2*(1/2) + (0-1/2)^2*(1/2)}$
$= \sqrt{2/8}$

$P= 0.5$

$σ=\sqrt{(p*(1 - p))/n}$

$σ=\sqrt{(0.5*(1-0.5))/2500}= \pm 1% = 0.01$

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If you let $x_1=1$ for heads and $x_2=0$ for tails and plug into the equations what do you get?  What are the probabilities?

Added:  Your added work is correct except that you have expressed $\sigma$ as a percentage without indicating it.  The absolute standard deviation is $\sqrt {2500 \cdot 0.5 \cdot (1-0.5)}=25$.  You have written $\sqrt {0.5 \cdot (1-0.5)/2500}$ which is $0.01=1\%$